# Pass variable name as parameter in SCSS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to write a mixin in SCSS to make CSS vars backward compatible. So that I want to first set the property value from an SCSS variable and then from CSS var and then if CSS var didn't work fine, SCSS var work at least.

Now the problem is when I want to pass a variable name to the mixin:

```
:root{
  --primary: red;
}
$primary : red;

@mixin backward($property, $var) {
  #{$property}: ${#{$var}};
  #{$property}: var(--#{$var});
}

body{
  @include backward(color, "primary");
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

At the place where I have written `${#{$var}}` I want to replace with the SCSS variable which name is in `$var`.
So, is there any way to pass SCSS var name and then parse it?

Comment: Thanks, @masoud. Although the linked question is not asked clearly, but also its answer is good enough to solve my problem too. <3